# displaying two months in angular datepicker

Tags: angularjs

I want to have a date picker which displays 2 months calendar at a time in angular. want the one like in [this](http://www.kayak.com). Please suggest how to implement that in angular

[image: Datepicker]

Comment: Look at here https://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/

Comment: bootstrap datepicker doesnt have an option to show 2 months in the calendar. it can show only one.

Comment: Probably I didn't understand what you mean for 2 months in the calendar, but if you check the Popup example from angular-ui you see 2 months.

Comment: Updated the question with screenshot of the datepicker i am looking for.

Comment: That is exactly what angular-ui does. Did you check it?

Comment: Yes i checked , it is displaying two datepicker components side by side . instead of displaying one date picker with 2 months

Comment: @Michelem This is an issue with AngularUI datepicker demo. But it doesn't support what OP's asking.

Comment: @swingmicro You can create you own datepicker directive based on Angular UI one, looks like it's quite easy.

Comment: any suggestions on how to create that directive, should i use jquery?

Comment: you need to change the template, you don't need any code (especially not jquery)

Comment: @r3plica I tested this and you cannot just update the template. The directive would need updating as well since there are several scope variables that are limited to the current moth. The directive would definitely need to be customized here is a pluker of just the template update: http://plnkr.co/edit/50O7LEJH9zPoR9SGd2cf?p=preview

Comment: I'm looking for a module like that one for Angular 2+...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The [angular-daterangepicker](https://github.com/fragaria/angular-daterangepicker) from fragaria seems to match the requirements here.

There is a live demo of the picker [here](https://awio.iljmp.com/5/drpdemogh), just click on the date-range in the upper right corner to see it in action.

Answer (score 1):

Datetime Range Picker is a good option too. Additionally, it has the time component.

http://rgkevin.github.io/datetimeRangePicker/#/home

[image: DateRange Time Picker]

Answer (score 0):

i need use this for angular 2+ (in angular-material).
possible ?